# Sort barh plot in python by count of values in bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to sort a barh plot in python by the count of numbers in the bar, ie the longest bar at the top and the rest descend. So far i have this;

```
df2=df1.groupby('Districts').count()

df2['recordnumber'].plot(kind='barh', ax=ax, alpha=a, 
legend=False, edgecolor='w', xlim=(0,max(df2['recordnumber'])),
title=ttl)
```

How can i now arrange the bars from highest to lowest number?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work round on this but it's not particularly Pythonic or elegant. Create another data frame using sort

```
df2=df1.groupby('Districts').count()
df2sort=df2.sort('recordnumber')

df2sort['recordnumber'].plot(kind='barh', ax=ax, alpha=a, 
legend=False, edgecolor='w', xlim=(0,max(df2sort['recordnumber'])),
title=ttl)
```